# Autowired bean in spock test null after downgrading spring from 4.3.x to 3.2.x

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spock, spring-test

I downgrade my application from spring 4.x to 3.x and now when I fire simple test in spock which using autowired bean, this bean is null.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Configuration.class)
class SomeTestClass extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService

    def "someService"(){
         expect:
         someService.returnHelloWorld() == "Hello World" // (<- NullPointer)

    }
}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After when I downgrade also spock-core/spring to 0.6-groovy-1.8 and groovy-all to 1.8 and fire my test it throws this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'someAnotherBean' defined in file
>   ../SomeBean.class: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception
>   isorg.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could
>   notinstantiate bean class [..SomeBean.class]: No default
>   constructorfound; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:..SomeBean.()

This bean contains contructor which i used to intizialize final fieds in class:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:someproperties.properties")
public class HeaderFactory {

private final SomeObject someObject;

    public HeaderFactory(@Value("${someProperty1}") String someProperty1, @Value("${someProperty2}") String someProperty2) {
        SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject(someProperty1,someProperty2);
       this.someObject = someObject;
    }
}
```

Everything worked pretty well before I dowgraded spring version. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think Spring supported automatic constructor injection as early as `3.2.x`, but I could be wrong. You could try adding an `@Autowired` annotation to the constructor.

Comment: Maybe you know any alternative of this ?

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: Spock-1.1 has a bug with Spring 3, please try spock-1.2 snapshot, or a stable jitpack.io build, see the readme at https://github.com/spockframework/spock for details.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a configuration class and define the problematic beans there:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {

    @Value("${someProperty1}") String prop1;
    @Value("${someProperty2}") String prop2

    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        SomeBean bean = new SomeBean(prop1, prop2);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.0.html#new-feature-java-config

Comment: Unffortonettly, above way dosen't work. App still throwing an exception about missing default constructor. Also tried inject properties (via fields) in my Component class but they are null :(. Any more ideas?

BTW. Shoud I use PropertySource annotation in my Configuration class?

Comment: @KamilDS can you post the code of the class that is throwing the exception? (the `SomeBean` class). I don't see it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by this way:

```
@Component
public class UrlBuilder {

    private final String host;
    private final String port;
    private final String protocol;

    @Autowired
    public UrlBuilder(Environment env) {
        this.protocol = env.getRequiredProperty("app.server.protocol").toLowercase();
        this.serverHost = env.getRequiredProperty("app.server.host");
        this.serverPort = env.getRequiredProperty("app.server.port", Integer.class);
    }
}
```

[Source](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-injecting-property-values-into-configuration-beans/)